# Exclude or not including item in python

Tags: python

I'm a learning programmer and i'm doing a challenge but i'm stuck the challenge is this:

Loop through each item in **items** again. If the character at index 0 of the current item is the letter "a", continue to the next one. Otherwise, print out the current member.
Example: ["abc", "xyz"] will just print "xyz".

And my code is this:

```
def loopy(items):
# Code goes here
if item == 'a':
    continue
elif:
    break
for item in times:
    print(item)
```

it wont pass. please help me i'm stuck and don't know how to do it.

Comment: `print([i for i in ["abc", "xyz"] if not i.startswith('a')])`

Answer (score 1):

RomamPerekhrest's comment is correct, but I believe this might be a better place to start for learning programmers.

```
# for all items in the list, get the single item
for item in items:
    # if the item at index 0 is not 'a'
    if item[0] != 'a':
        # print the item that doesn't start with 'a'
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to convert items from  `["abc", "xyz"]` to `['a', 'x']` :

```
items = list(map(lambda x:x[0], items))
```

Then you can check each item in a loop and see if it equals 'a'.